# How to create similar behavior as Gmails Contact manager

Tags: javascript, ajax, gmail, contacts

I would like to create something similar as Gmail's contact manager.

I'm not very experienced with JavaScript, I understand the basic concepts of AJAX and know my way around jQuery. But that is as far as it goes.

Book/blog recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a Java backend or if you don't mind deploying to Google App Engine, you might want to take a look at [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). They have excellent [tutorials](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/index.html) and [example applications](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/examples/), including a [Mail app](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Mail/Mail.html) that you might be able to modify to suit your needs.

If you'd rather not use GWT, you can use any of the several JavaScript UI Libraries out there along with any backend; [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Ext](http://www.extjs.com/), [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), [MochaUI](http://mochaui.com/), to name a few. You could also roll your own UI using the underlying cross-browser libraries (YUI, Ext JS, jQuery, MooTools, etc.) or even just plain old JavaScript/HTML/CSS/DOM.

It all depends on your requirements, how much control you want over your code, look-and-feel, behaviour and what your preference is.

Ideally, you'll want to brush up on JavaScript fundamentals and Object Oriented JavaScript as well as HTML/CSS and your server-side language, so that you can build an application with structured, clean and maintainable code. Books on the topic are easy to find.
Realistically, just find a tutorial in the development stack of your choice and continue from there.
It would be best to try and strike a balance of the two.

Comment: I may add that other options for powerful UI libraries are Sproutcore (http://sproutcore.com/) and Cappucino (http://cappuccino.org/). These will allow you to completely abstract your application from traditional web technologies (HTML/ CSS/DOM).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I don't know the exact solution to your question, but there are some open source applications available.You can have some idea after you go through the source.

[Gontact GTK+ contact manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gontact/)

As you mentioned Ajax take a look at this [PHP AJAX File Manager (PAFM)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pafm/)

And let me know if it was any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually designing something similar to the Gmail contacts manager.  I am using ExtJs with Alfresco as my repository.  I've only been working with extjs and javascript for about 3 months though (as of this writing), but I must say using a javascript library like extjs has helped me get acquainted with javascript much easier (Great community and tons of examples to help me online).  I'm sure you can do something similar with jquery.

I don't have any book recommendations, but I definitely would recommend browsing through StackOverflow and the forums of the library you are going to use.  Chances are, people have implemented something similar or have plugins (for extjs in my case) that will help you get to your goal much faster (and most likely much easier).

Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I have created similar project in 2007 end. It is Rails(Ruby) project here is the source code.

***It uses Ruby, Rails, JQuery***

http://github.com/insightmethods/address-ref

Just realized license file is not added **( But sure we make it open source )**